# How to inherit one class implement by C

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-class

I want to add method for one class  implemented by C

```py
from lru import LRU
class A(LRU):
    def foo(self):
        print("a")
```

lru is a lib from https://github.com/amitdev/lru-dict

error:“type ‘type’ is not an acceptable base type”

Comment: if you compile LRU by yourself, then you could use: `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary()` to load the library. Not sure if this works, but worth the try!

Comment: @bert I just want to make thing simple by using packed python wheel,Could you explain why the class implement by C can't be inherited?

Answer (score 0):

Writing Python's inheritable C/C++ types is contained in this [PEP 253](https://peps.python.org/pep-0253/). Also, you have [this guide](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/) that explains how to write inheritable types in C/C++.

Comment: This is basically a link-only answer, which is frowned upon on Stack Overflow. It would be better to explain why this type isn't inheritable, and refer to the PEP or guide if needed.